# Android - DialogFragment with Layout Containing Fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I am using a customized DialogFragment. In the `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, I inflate a layout that contains another fragment causing the app to crash. How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, more info please! Why is the cause of the crash according to Logcat? Can you show the code you are talking about including this other Fragment

Comment: My question is simple :) How do you place a fragment inside a dialog fragment?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot nest `Fragments` in other `Fragments` with XML-Layouts. You have to add them with code. To insert a `Fragment` into another `Fragment` you have to use a special `FragmentManager` - a child `FragmentManager`. You can get it from the parent `Fragment`:

```
//In the DialogFragment ('parent') get the child FragmentManager:
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.transaction.add(new MyCustomChildFragment(), "CustomTag");
```

I usually add child `Fragments` in `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: i couldn't understand your answer. getChildFragmentManager() is not available for DialogFragment.

Comment: Sure it is: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: just tried to nest Fragments in a DialogFragment with support library and it just works :)